# How to invoke yyerror() from flex?

Tags: bison, yacc, lex

I have `yyerror()` defined in my Bison file:

parser.y

```
...
%code {
  void yyerror(YYLTYPE* yyllocp, yyscan_t unused, const char** errorReturn, const char* msg);
}
...

void yyerror(YYLTYPE* yyllocp, yyscan_t unused, const char** errorReturn, const char* msg) {
    ...
}
```

And I'd like to invoke it in my flex file with a custom message if possible:

flex.l

```
%option reentrant bison-bridge bison-locations   
...


"]"                     return TOKEN(TCLOSEINDEX);
.                       {yyerror("Unknown token");}

%%
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: 'Evoke' and 'invoke' don't mean the same thing. It would be better to `return yytext[0];` to the parser and let it deal with the bad character as a syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put the declaration of `yyerror` in a `%code provides` block instead of a default `%code` block, it will be copied into the generated header file which will make the declaration available to your scanner implementation. (You need `provides` rather than `requires` because the declaration depends on the declaration of `YYLTYPE`.)

Of course, you will need to call it with all of its required arguments.

Comment: Thanks again rici!